# How to publish Electron app to Mac app store?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to distribute my Electron app to Mac App Store and I've followed so many solutions but unexpectedly this is not working at all.

```
Electron: 9.2.0 (latest stable version)
Electron-builder: 22.8.0 (latest version)
```

This is the entitlements for my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Once I remove this `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` then app is working really well. But once I've uploaded package to app store then it's rejecting this due to not enabling the sandbox mode.

But sadly, whenever I enable this sandbox then app stops working.
Please provide me any advice.

Comment: what fails in the sandbox mode?

Comment: Well, @yanikus. As far as I know, by enabling the `sandbox` you can't use the private API from Chromium. So this is why the app crashes.

Comment: There is a crash message or when I do code signing manually then window opens but just white page.

Comment: Not only for you, but this is happening for all Electron projects.

Comment: Instead of publishing to the app store, I'd recommend out distribution by notarization.

Comment: @tpikachu thanks. but the slack is still on app store and they've upgraded a few weeks ago. it's electron app?

Comment: Slack is running without a sandbox. You can check that. @yanikus

Comment: And what is the best approach?

Comment: As I said, you can just publish your app by notarization. And also it's easy to implement an auto-update feature.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.